# Keep CLion's project files separately from the project

Tags: clion

Is there anyway to keep CLion's project files (i.e. .idea directory) in a separate directory than the project? This feature already exists in IntelliJ IDE but I can't find something similar to CLion...

I'm looking for a structure like this one:

~/my_project/CMakelists.txt
~/my_project/other_source_files
~/project_files/my_project/.idea